# Navigate from one form to another

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do I navigate from one form to another in Silverlight on Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean by form a xaml page, but if you do than you could use the NavigationContext.Navigate to go to a different page.

Below is an example on how to do this:

```
Uri theUri = new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);  
NavigationContext.Navigate(theUri);
```

Or have a look at this blogpost to learn more about navigation in windows phone 7:
http://chriskoenig.net/index.php/2010/05/16/wp7-part-3-navigation/

Answer (score 2):

In windows phone 7 or silverlight we don't have forms its only pages.

For navigating from one page to other you have to create a new instance of Uri then pass this Uri to `NavigationService.Navigate`

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("strFileName", UriKind.Relative));
```

NavigationService is in System.Windows.Navigation